# Most efficient way to get a large directory listing over network

Tags: macos, windows-server-2003, find, directory-listing

I'm searching for specific files on a Windows 2003 server directory that contains thousands of files. The directory is part of a network volume that's mounted on my Mac.

Right now I'm using find:

```
find . -name \*STRING\*
```

But it's still not very fast. Is there a way to make this more fast/efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Install Locate32 on the server (http://www.locate32.net/), then RDP (remote-connect) to the server so you can search using the tray icon.

It will create a database of all files on the server, and searches are almost instantaneous.

I even use it in an XP VM to point to multiple server shares.

Comment: Wow, Locate32 is *fast*. Though a workaround, this is definitely helpful—thanks for the tip.

Comment: @DanB: Remember, if the answer fixed it, mark it as accepted with the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @Mark I was looking for a solution that would run on Mac and/or Mac-accessible command line client, so while this was an acceptable workaround—and one I'm glad to know about!—it didn't answer my original question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're looking from your Mac at a shared directory from a Windows 2003 server.  If that is the case, then yes.  The short answer: List the files to a temporary file on the Win2k3 server using a program local to the Win2k3 server.  Transfer that file to your Mac.

You're getting killed by the latency of requests to/from the server; the above will mitigate that.  I don't know exact commands; I just know you need to do the search locally to the Win2k3 machine and transfer the result to the Mac.

Comment: You've guessed correctly... I've updated to reflect the actual setup.